# hash holding the values of address of a 2 D array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

In Perl, how can I create a hash, whose values will be the address of a 2D array?
I need to get the values of the 2D array dynamically, too.

Please give me the exact coding. I am breaking my head.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask ; This isn't a "Give me the codez" site.

Comment: I am happy to help a new Perl user however demanding the exact code is very rude. We are here to help each other not do your job for you. I have given you an example that teaches you the lessons that you need, and a link to documentation so you can teach yourself.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
my %hash = (
    foo => [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
    bar => [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
);
```

2D array is modelled as array of arrays here.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and hashes can only take scalar values, however an array reference (created using `[]`, among other ways) are scalars. Therefore creating nested arrays is done using this construct. Think of it as:

```
$array_element_1 = ['row 1 column 1', 'row 1 column 2'];
$array_element_2 = ['row 2 column 1', 'row 2 column 2'];
$array_reference = [$array_element_1, $array_element_2];
%hash = ( 'key' => $array_reference);
```

except without all of the intermediate storing. These are called anonymous references (since they don't require that you give the original structure a name before creating the reference to the structure). Note that anonymous hash references are created using `{}`. Read more at [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).